# Spring MVC - clearing fields

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a domain object which I am presenting on a typical form.  Here is a simplified example:

```
public class Name implements Keyed {

    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private Number key;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Let's say I have two type of users whom can each modify these Name objects.  For some silly reason one group is not allowed to see / edit the middle names of the users.  So I leave that field off of the form (no hidden field either).

Is there anyway to keep Spring from clearing that middle name field?  I could create a new object for this, but it seems like duplication which shouldn't be needed.

Is there a way to keep data which hasn't been modified (i.e. it wasn't displayed to the user, hence couldn't have been changed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that with spring binding this is simply not possible.  You are basically forced into creating a near copy of your domain object, and remove fields which are not to be displayed on the page itself.  While unfortunate, it is simply how spring binding works, as a new instance will be created by spring for you before your method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably store the middle name on the session (for read only users) and retrieve it upon form submission.

Comment: While true, this is a simplified example.  The piece I am working on is an object with deep composition.  For instance, I might choose not to display the middle name.  However, I'm really dealing with a Person object, who has a date of birth, email address, physical address, etc...  I then have to pick and choose what to place on the session, and upon subsequent submission reset all those fields which were not displayed (which could be unwieldy).